# SQL: OPENROWSET not returning data correctly

Tags: sql, t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2012, openrowset

I am trying to use OPENROWSET to query a csv file which works well 90% of the time but for some reasons some .csv files were returning this error:

```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 5 (Status Description).
```

or this error:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
```

My Query looks like this:

```
select * from OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\File.csv', FORMATFILE= 'E:\schema.xml') AS a
```

My format file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
 <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\0\n\0" MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Column1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Column2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Column3" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Column4" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Column5" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I found that if I copy the contents of my .csv into a brand new file and save it then run again the query will complete successfully. But this is not ideal so after tweaking the format file and running the same query I now get this as a result:

```
Column 1 Column2 Column3 Column4
ÿþD             
m               
m               
m               
m               
m
```

When my original data looks like this:

```
 Column 1 Column2   Column3 Column4
 Abc      elephant  Yes     Job has finished.               
 def      tiger     Yes     Job has finished.
 xyz      monkey    Yes     Job has finished.   
 ghi      dog       Yes     Job has finished.
```

It seems that now the query is completing but is returning garbage data.

Does anyone know how to fix this so that I can return accurate results?

Comment: Open one of the .csv files that causes the error in Notepad, and click File, Save As.  In the Save As dialog, look at the bottom and see if it is Unicode (or anything other than ANSI).  If it is, change it to ANSI and save it and see if it works.

Comment: Actually, reading your question more carefully I'm pretty sure that Unicode encoding is the problem because ÿþ is a byte-order mark.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: You can run a command such as `cmd /a /c type myfile.csv > myansifile.csv` to convert the file to ANSI if it is Unicode.

Comment: Tony you da man! It is Unicode and actually it generated via powershell with the -Encoding Unicode command. Did not know this was a problem.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I'll write the answer in a minute when my PC boots.  Please accept it as the answer--I'm shooting for 200 pts today.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ÿþ is a byte-order mark, which tells me that it's a Unicode encoded file.  Whatever is reading the file isn't smart enough to handle Unicode files, so it is unable to read it.

You'll need to modify whatever is creating the file to use ANSI, or modify what you're using to read the file to handle Unicode.

To work around the issue, you can convert the file to ANSI using the type command and redirect the output to a new file:

`cmd /a /c type myfile.csv > myansifile.csv`